# Directly POST JSONObject via retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Can I send JSON directly via retrofit like this:

```
@POST("rest/workouts")
Call<CreateWorkoutSuccessAnswer> createWorkout(@NonNull @Body JSONObject jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TypedInput

```
@POST("rest/workouts")
Call<CreateWorkoutSuccessAnswer> createWorkout(@NonNull @Body TypedInput body);
```

And to form param:

```
TypedInput in = new TypedByteArray("application/json", jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

And use **in** as a parameter for request.

Comment: I tried to search in google but did not find. How can I plug TypedInput

Comment: You can also try this:

@POST("rest/workouts")
Call<CreateWorkoutSuccessAnswer> createWorkout(@NonNull @Body RequestBody requestBody);

RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonObject.toString());

Answer (score 1):

You can directly post JSON objects using GSONs `JsonObject` class.

The reason Googles `JSONObject` does not work is that retrofit uses GSON by default and tries to serialize the JSONObject parameter as a POJO. So you get something like:

```
{
    "JSONObject":
    {
        <your JSON object here>
    }
}
```

If what you are doing requires you to use `JSONObject` then you can simply convert between the two using the String format of the object.